# Js-jq dublicates .find

Tags: javascript, jquery

jq функция

```
  $( ".new-mark" ).click(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var modal = $('#mark-modal');
  $('.mark-input').val('');
  $('.mark-input').change(function() {
    self.find('span').html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

которая привязана к элементу

```
    @foreach ...
    <td class="new-mark" style="display:none;">
<span></span>
</td>
    @endforeach
```

по первому вызову `self.find('span')` возвращает 1 элемент, по второму 2, и так далее. Все спаны имеют одинаковый текст, а каждый должен иметь свой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Совет дня:* не назначайте обработчики событий внутри других обработчиков событий.

```
$(function() {
  var self;
  $( ".new-mark" ).click(function() {
    self = $(this);
    $('.mark-input').val('');
  });
  $('.mark-input').change(function() {
    self.find('span').html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

В Вашем коде действие `$('.mark-input').change(function() { ... });` выполняется на каждый `$(".new-mark").click`. То есть для события `$('.mark-input').change` добавляется новый обработчик. Когда событие `$('.mark-input').change` происходит, все прикрепленные обработчики выстреливают один за другим.

Весь показанный код следует обернуть в обработчик `$(document).ready` - это как раз то событие, внутри которого можно/следует назначать обработчики других событий. Тогда переменная `self` не будет засорять глобальную область видимости.

Comment: тоже не работает

Comment: @DimaRashevskiy работает, Вы неаккуратно скопировали мой код ).

Comment: сработало после вашей правки. Можно по поводу событий пару предложений?

Comment: @DimaRashevskiy Потому что Вы используете ее в другой функции - обработчике события `$('.mark-input').change`.

Comment: есть способ избежать такого свободного назначения переменных в данном случае?